# Nested switch gives error and indicates virus (trojan)

Tags: c++

Trying to make a program using switch case (nested switch) my system alerted me that my program has a virus (trojan). How is it even possible? I am new to programming (complete novice) so I would be grateful for any help.

The task - to make automated telephonic reply system based upon requirements (just something I wanted to try).

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void customer_service()
{
    cout<<"Kindly wait for our employees to contact you";
}
void feedback()
{
    cout<<"Kindly record your feedback after the beep";
}
void offer()
{
    cout<<"You are entitled to accept our one-time offer. You will be directed to one of our employees shortly\n";
}
void satisfied()
{
    cout<<"Thanks a lot for calling. Have a great day ahead";
}
int main()
{
    int input,yes_no;
    cout<<"\nPress 1 if you would want to directly contact our employee\n";
    cout<<"\nPress 2 if you wan to give a feedback\n";
    cout<<"\nPress 3 if ypu would want to know about our offers\n";
    cout<<"\nPress 4 if you are satisfied with our service\n";
    cout<<"\nKindly press the required key\n";
    cin>>input;
    switch (input)
    {
    case 1:
        customer_service();
        break;
    case 2:
        feedback();
        break;
    case 3:
        offer();
        cout<<"Would you like to accept our one time offer? You will get a 50% decrease in tariff";
        cin>>yes_no;
        switch (yes_no)
        {
        case 1:
            cout<<"Congratulations! You have won our one time offer";
            break;
        default:
            cout<<"Guess you didn't like our offer";
            break;
        }
        break;
    case 4:
        satisfied();
        break;
    default:
        cout<<"Kindly press either one of '1, 2, 3 or 4' keys. Thankyou.";
    }
    cin.get();
    return 0.00;
}
```

[This is the indication of Trojan and the program not executing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJPRk.png)

Comment: I'd guess it's something in your text that's triggering a signature match to malware... maybe "one-time offer"?  Try changing some of your text to see if you can narrow it down

Comment: That's one of the politest programs I've ever seen.

Comment: Add some indentation into your code to make it readable.

Answer (score 2):

It's a false positive.

You may be able to help the situation by initialising your variables. As it is, you do not check that reading into `yes_no` succeeded, so your program has undefined behaviour. That could make your AV think that you are trying to write a memory exploit.

Otherwise, get better AV!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Lightness Races in Orbit. My program worked (without that virus indication).

Answer (score 1):

Some anti virus programs simply have false positives. Just whitelist in this case or get another anti virus.
OR your toolchain itself is infected and you compile bad stuff into your programs (then it's time to clean up your OS)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code.

Programs like 360 total security are anti-malware products that are designed to run on your mother's machine. They are not appropriate on a programmer's machine. They deal poorly with an executable file that appears from nowhere. Uninstall and consider something less aggressive, Windows Defender for example.

Answer (score 0):

Nested switch cases will work work for sure.
First try like instead of using second switch case use if else condition if still it shows TROJAN thing then its a problem with your compiler.